# CSS speech bubble applied to SVG

Tags: css, svg

I suspect I might be missing something fundamental here, but is it possible to apply CSS created speech bubbles (e.g. http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles) to SVG shapes?

I'm working with d3, and the speech bubbles created purely in javascript/svg tend to be harder work, and look less polished, so I'd love to be able to do something like...

```
<svg class="oval-speech">
<text>some text inside the speech bubble</text>
<svg>
```

I can't really rely on the css-only option applied to p elements, because my entire chart is SVG based.

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: Use a foreignObject tag and then you can use html with p and css just like your link does.

Comment: thanks - that got it working!